# How to insert an "All" option in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

How do I write the code for the "All" list item in the drop down list such that when "All" is selected, the entire list of items in the drop down list is selected?

Note: My "All" list item is in the same drop downlist as the rest of the items (which are databounded) that should be selected when the user selects "All".

My current code:

```
if (ModelDropDownList.SelectedValue == "ALL")
{
    foreach (ListItem modelno in ModelDropDownList.Items)
    {
        modelno.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the question. If you already have that "All"-ListItem you just have to check if it was selected, if so you know that the user wants to select all.

Comment: Basically, I want to write the code for the "All" option in the drop down list such that when the user selects "All", the program equates it to all the items in the drop down list. Problem is, the item "All" is in the same dropdownlist as the rest of the items that should be selected when the user selects it.

Comment: can you share the code you have?

Comment: @Lucy: but that depends on what you use as `DataSource`. If it's a database table and you want to filter another table by the foreign-key you have to change the query that it don't filter by that column. It's also not so difficult to skip the `All`-item: `dropDown.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Text != "All")`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write a seperate method that is called when "All" is selected that manually makes the selection of all items.

this should help
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18063/Multi-select-Dropdown-list-in-ASP-NET

Comment: seems like there is no easy way to achive this, there are two ways to solve this problem, by either adding checkboxes to the dropdownlist like so http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24205/MultiSelect-Dropdown-Control or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and 

or assign all selected values to an array depending what you want to use them for